# Unable to use variable

Tags: c#, forms

I have the following problem. I've created a variable and when I use it in code it gives me an error:  `Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.assemblyPath'  Form Change Wallpaper`

My code

```
public partial claass Form1: Form
{
   private string assemblyPath = Path.GetFullPath(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

   private static string[] GetAllWallpapers(string daytime)
   {
      string dataPath = assemblyPath + @"..\..\..\..\data"; // Error line
   }
}
```

The rest of the code has no problem

Comment: Do you know what `static` means when applied to a member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assemblyPath` is an instance member - it belongs to a specific instance of `Form1`. On the other hand, `GetAllWallpapers` is a `static` method - it belongs to the class as a whole, not to any specific instance, and thus can't access any member of a specific instance.

To solve this issue, you can either make `assemblyPath` `static` or remove the `static` modifier from `GetAllWallpapers`. From the context, `assemblyPath` doesn't seem to contain any information that's specific to an instance, and it can't be modified by any instance, so it makes sense to make it `static` and call it a day.